# Disable decoding of HTML entities in Chrome developer tools

Tags: html, google-chrome, decode, entities, developer-tools

I am working in Chrome developer tools and looking for a way to show HTML entities by default.

The view I see is this:

[image]

Whereas, the view I need is this:

[image]

Does anybody know how I can enable the view I need?

I know there is a theme engine for Chrome but is there an existing feature that fits my needs?

Thanks guys ;)

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to display the true source code?

Comment: Nope. :( However, there is Burpsuite... I just use this. But I'm still interested in a solution to this issue :)

Comment: In your source code you have written `&amp;` or `&`?

Comment: I don't know how to make developer tools show the unencoded version in the inspect window, but I do notice that if I right click an element and copy it, then when I paste it into another application it pastes the original (encoded) text, not the decoded version that Chrome was showing me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same question and discovered that with chrome, right-click > View Source code, shows the pure un-decoded(un-evaluated) html entities while the right-click > inspect option seems to evaluate them... may help someone:)

Comment: This does not always work because View Source reloads the document, even sometimes [sending the wrong UA on mobile development](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1257521#c3).

Answer (score 1):

In Google Chrome the correct way to see the actual source of the document that is currently loaded is to click the **Sources** tab and choose the file from the tree on the left. If you have a unique string on the line that you're searching for, you can press **Ctrl-Shift-F** to search all files for that string.

- `RightClick -> View Source` is incorrect because it reloads the document, which may cause [unexpected behaviour](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1257521).
- `Inspect Element` is incorrect because it displays the current DOM, not the HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

You can't: The DOM Inspector shows a view of the DOM, not the source code.

The HTML has already been parsed and the entities converted to characters in text nodes.

The Inspector shows an HTML-like view because it is easy to understand. It doesn't reflect the original source code.

Browsers have an explicit "View Source" feature if you want to see the source code.